# How do I iterate over "Items" and extract properties and values (VB Net/c#)

Tags: c#, arrays, json, vb.net

I would like to iterate over the items in the json shown below. Not every item has all the same fields/key values.
The items I want to iterate over are found at "items":

How do I iterate over these items?
I can get the items into an array called Items:
Dim ParseJson As JObject = JObject.Parse(APIReturn)
Dim Items = ParseJson.SelectToken("items").ToString()

How can I iterate over this array, and extract the values from each item?

As I get each item, I want to extract the "title", "date", and "category". How do get these values from the json?

```
{
    "title": "Massapequa Park July 2023",
    "date": "2023-07-01T20:52:43.581Z",
    "location": {
        "title": "Massapequa Park, New York, USA",
        "city": "Massapequa Park",
        "tzid": "America/New_York",
        "latitude": 40.68038,
        "longitude": -73.45512,
        "cc": "US",
        "country": "United States",
        "admin1": "New York",
        "asciiname": "Massapequa Park",
        "geo": "geoname",
        "geonameid": 5126187
    },
    "range": {
        "start": "2023-07-01",
        "end": "2023-07-08"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "Holiday 1",
            "date": "2023-07-01",
            "hdate": "H1",
            "category": "Holiday ",
        },
        {
            "title": "Meeting: 9:19pm",
            "date": "2023-07-01T21:19:00-04:00",
            "category": "Meeting",
            "title_orig": "Meeting",
        },
        {
            "title": "MiniFast begins",
            "date": "2023-07-06T03:42:00-04:00",
            "category": "fast",
            "subcat": "mini fast",
            "memo": "short fast"
        },
        {
            "title": "Stop Mini Fast",
            "date": "2023-07-06",
            "hdate": "Hold 1",
            "category": "fast",
            "subcat": "mini fast",
            "memo": "short fast"
        },
        {
            "title": "Fast ends",
            "date": "2023-07-06T21:08:00-04:00",
            "category": "Light",
            "subcat": "fast",
            "memo": "Old Shirt"
        },
        {
            "title": "18 Before Dusk: 8:09pm",
            "date": "2023-07-07T20:09:00-04:00",
            "category": "Ready Lights",
            "title_orig": "18 Before Dusk",
            "memo": "Nachos"
        },
        {
            "title": "Holiday 7",
            "date": "2023-07-08",
            "hdate": "7th Holiday",
            "category": "Holiday ",
        },
        {
            "title": "Meeting: 9:17pm",
            "date": "2023-07-08T21:17:00-04:00",
            "category": "Meeting",
            "title_orig": "Meeting",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That was a mistake, dog jumping on mouse. Corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `Newtonsoft.Json`, then it's simple-enough:

1. Use `JToken.Parse` on the response body (`APIReturn`) and then verify the parsed `JToken` is an `JObject` (as it could be a `null` literal, or a `JArray`, or something else).
2. Use `JObject.Property("items")` to get the `JProperty` for the `"items":` property.
3. Verify that the `JProperty.Value` is a `JArray` (as opposed to `null` or another `JObject` or something else).
4. Iterate over the `JTokens` in that `JArray`: test each one to verify it's a `JObject` (or use Linq's `OfType<JObject>()`) and then safely extract the desired values.

Something like this:

```
String jsonText = ... // await File.ReadAllTextAsync( @"2023-07-01-json.txt" );

if( JToken.Parse( jsonText ) is JObject root )
{
    if( root.Property( "items" ) is JProperty p && p.Value is JArray items )
    {
        var extractedItems = items
            .OfType<JObject>()
            .Select( o => (
                title   : o.Property( "title"    )?.Value.ToString(),
                date    : o.Property( "date"     )?.Value.ToString(),
                category: o.Property( "category" )?.Value.ToString()
            ) )
            .ToList();
            
        extractedItems.Dump(); // `Dump` is a LinqPad method
    }
}
```

Screenshot proof:

[image]

---

<sub>(Ignore how LinqPad reports the ValueTuple member names as `Item1`, `Item2`, and `Item3`: C# IntelliSense will let you correctly dereference those members by the names `title`, `date`, and `category` in code).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
Dim Items As JArray = JObject.Parse(jsonString).SelectToken("items")

Dim result = Items.Select(Function(x)
                           Return New With {Key .Title = x("title").ToString,
                                            Key .Category = x("category").ToString}
                                  End Function).ToList()
```

Comment: Very simple. I like that. Will implement this as my solution. Thank You